# Image into the UITextView

Tags: iphone

Is this possible to insert the image into the UITextView from the Gallery. If this is possible then how this can be done? Is there any default method of the UITextView? Please suggest me.

Comment: If you mean inserting an image into the actual content of a UITextView, then no, this is not possible. Might I ask what you're trying to achieve here? (Just to get a better idea of your context)

Answer (score 2):

No you can not. Rather you can take `UIImageView`, set image and take transparent `UITextView` and set your text view on image view.

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot be done. You want to create a UIView and add a UIImageView and a UITextView as subviews of it.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you can't. If you want that because you want your text wrap around your image, I suggest that you use `UIWebView` and html instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 60, 0)];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, textView.contentSize.height, 60, 60)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // for testing
[textView addSubView:view];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UiImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"]];
[view addSubView:imgView];
```

// catching textViewDidChange delegate method

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
   view.frame = CGRectMake(130, textView.contentSize.height, 60, 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be already solved but if someone still looking for it then.

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image inTextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (!image ||
        !textView)
    {
        return;
    }
    CGFloat padding = 10; // 10px for the padding for displaying image nicely
    CGFloat scaleFactor = image.size.width / (CGRectGetWidth(self.textView.frame) - padding);
    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    NSAttributedString *attributedStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
    [self.textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:attributedStringWithImage];
    // Uncomment following line if you want to have a new line after image
    // [self.textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
}
```